# Can I apply decomposition methods for this scheduling problem

Tags: scheduling, benders-decomposition, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

I have a centralized optimization problem for a residential area in the context of a smart grid and load flexibility. So let's say I have 10 buildings and each of them has an electric heating device. Further each building has a photovoltaic PV system that generates renewable energy. Now the goal of the centralized optimization problem is to schedule the heating activities of all buildings such that the overall usage of the total reneable energy (sum of all the PV generation of all buildings) is maximized.

Basically every building has 24 decision variables (one for each hour): x_1, ..., x_24
The quantiy the (continious) power consumption of the electric heating device in each hour. Of course we also have some thermal constraints for the room temperature such that it is not possible to heat with full power during all hours. Moreover, each building has a PV generation that is given exogeneously meaning that this is a parameter: PV_1, ..., PV_24

So the goal of the centralized optimizer is to choose x_1, ..., x_24 for all 10 buildings such that the PV self consumption rate, is maximized. The total electrical power P_total for the residential area for one timeslot is just the sum of the x_1s, ..., x_24s for all buildings. The same is valid for the total PV generation PV_total of the residential area. Now we want to minimize the sum of PV_total - P_total over all 24 hours of the day (this maximizes the self-consumption rate of PV).

I hope you have understood the basics of this problem (if not I can give you more information). My fundamental question now is, whether I can use one of the following decomposition methods to transform this centralized large optimization problem into distributed smaller problems that could be solved by the buildings themselves. Basically I would like to know if I can use one of these methods:

ADMM: Alternating methods of multipliers

Dual decomposition

Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition

Benders decomposition

I'd appreciate every comment.

Update: Here is the complete optimization problem[image]

x_t_b and y_t_b are the decision variables for all timeslots t and all buildings b. The objective is to minimize the surplus power in the residential area. The surplus power is calculated by subtracting the total electrical deamand of the area from the total PV geneartion. But only the positive surplus power should be minimized. I use the Big-M approach to incorporate this into the model with the two big M parameters and an auxillary binary variable h^positive. I have two thermal storage systems (modelled by T^UFH and V^DHWuse) which have upper and lower limits. x_t_b is the decision variable for heating up the T^UFH_b and y_t_b the decision variables for heating up the V^DHWuse_b. Only on of them can be heated up at one time slot. To model this I use a binary auxilliary variable h^Aux for each building and each time slot. The total demand P^total comprises the electrical demand of the heat pumps and the inflexible demand P^Demand that is a parameter.

Comment: Must the values of $x_1,\dots,x_{24}$ agree across buildings?

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your comment. No, each building can have different x_1, ..., x_24 values and each building has different PV_1, ..., PV_24 values.

Comment: Then what prevents solving each building separately?

Comment: If every building just optimizes on its own, the results are quite bad. This is because if one building for example produces more PV during one time slot than it can consume, other buildings do not know this and can't react to it if every building just optimizes based on local information.

Comment: Your description sounds like the objective function is a sum across buildings and there are no linking constraints across buildings.  So solving each building separately is equivalent to solving them together.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your comment. I can gurantee you that solving each building separately is definetely NOT the same as solving them together. Well there are linking constraints and I wrote 'The total electrical power P_total for the residential area for one timeslot is just the sum of the x_1s, ..., x_24s for all buildings. The same is valid for the total PV generation PV_total of the residential area.'

Comment: As written in the previous comment. If one building has a high value for the PV generation for one timeslot that surpasses its maximal electrical power, the surplus PV generation will not be 'seen' by the other buildings and they can't react to it. Let's say another building has not PV generation during this time slot (maybe because of a cloud passing the PV system). If this building optimizes for its own it will not consume high power during this time slot as its PV generaiton is low. But in a centralized way it would use high power as there is surplus PV generation from the other building

Comment: Those sums sound more like definitions for the purpose of describing the objective rather than true constraints.  I think you are more likely to get useful responses if you write out a complete formulation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment RobPratt. I have uploaded the full optimization problem and a short describtion of it. I stil would like to know if I can or cannot use the mentioned decomposition methods to solve it. I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for adding the formulation.  Assuming $\Delta t$ is a nonnegative coefficient, you can simplify the formulation by omitting $h_t^\text{positive}$, $P_t^{\text{Surplus}^-}$, and the associated constraints.  Instead, you need only impose
$$P_t^{\text{Surplus}^+} \ge P_t^\text{PVtotal} - P_t^\text{total} \quad \text{for all $t$} \tag 1$$
to get the desired behavior of minimizing the positive surplus.

It looks like you still need some constraints to enforce the relationships between $T$ and $V$ and the rest of the model.  Currently, $T$ and $V$ appear by themselves.

If you substitute the expressions for $P_t^\text{PVtotal}$ and $P_t^\text{total}$ (or use implicit/defined variables) and treat $(1)$ as the linking/complicating constraints, the rest of the problem decomposes by building, so you might benefit from applying Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition with one block per building.

---

Update to answer your additional questions:

By substitution, I meant replacing $(1)$ with
$$P_t^{\text{Surplus}^+} \ge \sum_{b=1}^B P_{t,b}^\text{PV} - \sum_{b=1}^B \left((x_{t,b}+y_{t,b})P_b^\text{HPmax}+P_{t,b}^\text{Demand}\right) \quad \text{for all $t$} \tag{1$'$}$$

To treat $(1)$ or $(1')$ as linking constraints, some automated Dantzig-Wolfe implementations allow you to specify the block-angular structure by using constraint attributes.  For example, see [this Getting Started example](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpug&docsetVersion=15.1&docsetTarget=ormpug_decomp_gettingstarted.htm&locale=en) from the SAS documentation.

Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition applies when you have a set of linking/complicating constraints whose omission makes the resulting problem much easier.
In contrast, Benders decomposition applies when you have a set of linking/complicating variables such that fixing the values of these variables makes the problem much easier.  In principle, either decomposition algorithm can be used for any subset you choose, but the best performance is obtained when your problem has some structure where only a small percentage of constraints or variables are complicating.  The Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition I suggested seems the most natural for your problem, and it matches your intuition of wanting to solve the buildings separately.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your answer. I really appreciate your help.
 I have several additional questions:
1) What do you mean by 'If you substitute the expressions for P^PVtotal_t and P^total_t'
2) How can I treat (1) as the linking constraints?
3) Can I also use Benders decomposition? What are the prerequesits for that? I think I need linking variables? What is the difference between linking variables and linking constraints? PS: Yes you are right. I have some constraints that link the decision variables x and y to T and V.

Comment: Would anyone mind asking my follow up questions (see commen above)? I'd really appreciate it and I'd be quite thankful.

Comment: @PeterBe, I added some responses to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer RobPratt and your effort. As I have no experience whatsovever regarding decomposition I still have some questions.  1) What are 'linking variables'? Maybe you can pinpoint them in my example? 
2)Did I understand correctly that basically I can use both Benders and Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition for every mixed integer linear program (but the are not beneficial for every problem) ? 3) What about the dual decomposition method or the ADMM method. Can I also apply them in my case? I'd appreciate further comments.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for my last comments? I'd be quite thankful for every comment

Comment: ??????????????????????

Comment: If I wanted to use Bender's decomposition, how would the problem formulation look like? What are the linking variables?

Comment: You haven't shown the whole formulation, but so far I don't see any natural structure for Benders decomposition beyond the simple approach of treating all integer variables as complicating (as in Benders' 1962 paper).  When they are fixed to specific values, the resulting problem is LP.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your answer. But the integer variables only belong to the buildings so I do not think that they are linking variables. Of course I could fix them and then solve the centralized LP of all buildings combined. But this way the optimization problems of the individual buildings could not be solved in a distributed manner.

Comment: Dantzig-Wolfe and Benders do not require more than one subproblem to be effective.  That is why the term *complicating* is sometimes used instead of *linking*.  The resulting LP across all buildings should still solve relative quickly (because it is LP instead of MILP), even without being able to solve each building separately.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt. So basically Benders decomposition is nothing else but fixing the integer variables and then solving the resulting LP model? From what I read in your answers the Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition works quite different compared to Benders. However, I read on the Internet (https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_state_the_difference_or_pros_cons_of_benders_decomposition_vs_dantzig-wolfe_decomposition_methods_with_regards_to_stochastic_problems) that Benders decomposition is the dual of Dantzig-Wolfe.

Comment: Yes, they are duals of each other. No, Benders is more general than what you describe, but that choice of complicating variables is the simplest and is the basis of his 1962 paper. Note also that both decomposition methods alternate between MILP and LP solves.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your comment. So in my optimization problem I could just assign random values to the integer variables and fix them and solve the remaining LP. This would be called Benders decomposition (in its basic form), right?

Comment: No, there is nothing random about Benders decomposition.  The values for both the master variables and the subproblem variables are determined by solving optimization problems.  Solving the ILP master and then solving the resulting LP subproblem would together constitute one iteration of Benders decomposition.  I suggest reading the appropriate sections in one of the books recommended in the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt for your comment and effort. So the master variables are the integer variables, right? How do I obtain the values of them? I have understood how the second phase of Benders works. Here you just fix the integer variables and then solve the resulting LP. But the question is how I can get the values for one iteration of Benders for the integer variables that are then fixed.

Comment: As I am somehow in a hurry, I'd appreciate if you could comment on the last question about how to set up the Benders decomposition (this will be then my last question regarding this concern and I will accept your answer).

Comment: In each iteration, the values of the Benders master variables are obtained by solving the Benders master problem, which contains just those variables and the current set of Benders (feasibility and optimality) cuts for those variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot RobPratt for your great help and effort (I accepted the answer and awarded the bounty to you).

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBe.  Glad to help.